# How do I slide/open specific menu item using javascript / jquery on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, pageload

I'm new to java and jquery scripting, I've managed to learn how to open menu on item mouse click, but how do I open specific menu on page load?

I'm using this:

```
<!-- menu -->
<div id="menuone">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>About</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Projects</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">project1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">project2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">project3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- menu end -->
```

and my javascript on click is this:

```
function initMenu() {
  $('#menu ul').hide();
  $('#menu li a').click(
    function() {
         $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');               
      }
    );
  } 
 $(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

but my quest is: how do I open specific item(s) on page load? How do I open menu item 2 for example ("about"), or menu utem 3 ("projects"), etc...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quite easy actually;

```
$('#menu li a:eq(1)').trigger('click'); //open "about"
$('#menu li a:eq(2)').trigger('click'); //open "projects"
```

hope I helped

Answer (score 1):

Put an id to your `a` tags like

```
<div id="menuone">
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="about">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="projects">Projects</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">project1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">project2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">project3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and then pass an id of your choice to your function like

```
// Pay attention to pass id to function
function initMenu(id)
{
    $('#menu ul').hide();
    $('#menu li a').click(
    function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');               
    });

    // Add following lines
    if (typeof(id) != 'undefined')
    {
        $('#'+id).click();
    }
} 

$(document).ready(function() {initMenu('projects');});
```

Then to change you can use instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {initMenu('about');});
```